# Why don't my 2 devices see the same key/values in NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore?

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, key-value-store

I am testing my app which stores settings in UserDefaults and NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore. Everything seems to be working correctly. The code stores and retrieves values from both stores. I check the FileManager.default.ubiquityIdentityToken to be sure the app is "online" with iCloud. Key-Value Storage is checked in the iCloud Capabilities. The devices are an iPad Pro and an iPhone 11 Pro Max.

The problem is that the two devices do not seem to see the same KeyValue store. Each one sees only what it stored. I added store.synchronize calls and that had no apparent effect.

This app is unpublished. Could that be the problem? Do unpublished apps have the same access to iCloud?

Is there a way to look at an app's iCloud KV storage independent of the app? I haven't found any.

Comment: have you tried to register for `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.didChangeExternallyNotification` notification to debug if any changes are actually registered?

Comment: @witekbobrowski Have not, but I am not sure what that would add. I f I get no notification, I am in the same situation. If I do, then I still have no idea why I cannot see the new entries.

Comment: Are both devices logged into the same iCloud account?

Comment: Yes, both devices on the same Apple ID, my personal account. Plus I have lgged a simulator in to the same account. Same results on the simulator.

Comment: Same here I used same apple id on two devices and they give different `FileManager.default.ubiquityIdentityToken ` ids